# Wrap HTML attributes on new lines set by user when formatting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In our team some people use Webstorm and others use Visual Studio Code.
Webstorm aligns attributes vertically when they're put on a new line by the user. It will align with the last attribute in the line. Visual Studio Code has a setting where you can wrap the attributes on format, but it wraps all attributes.

It would be nice if both editors would handle formatting the same.

I've tried several extensions (Prettier, Beautify, Alignment, Code alignment, Better Align) in Visual Studio Code, but none does what I want it to do.
Does anybody know of any setting or extension I might have missed that does what I want? Or is it simply not possible in Visual Studio Code?

**User setting**

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned",
```

**Result** (how VS Code aligns attributes)

```
<input type="text"
       name="input_name"
       placeholder="What's your name">
```

**Desired result** (how Webstorm aligns attributes)

```
<input type="text" name="input_name"
                   placeholder="What's your name">
```

Answer (score 29):

Try these options for the `html.format.wrapAttributes` setting.

```
  // Wrap attributes.
  //  - auto: Wrap attributes only when line length is exceeded.
  //  - force: Wrap each attribute except first.
  //  - force-aligned: Wrap each attribute except first and keep aligned.
  //  - force-expand-multiline: Wrap each attribute.
  //  - aligned-multiple: Wrap when line length is exceeded, align attributes vertically.
```

Comment: is a way to use this only for attribs in brakcets []? like in angular?

Comment: What do we do with these options?

Comment: @Jim like so `"html.format.wrapAttributes":"force-aligned"` in your `settings.json`

Comment: `force-expand-multiline` for the win ;)