# How to enforce new line per attribute in vue using Prettier in VS Code?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I am currently using [Prettier Version: 9.5.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) for Vue in VSCode.

This is my current code

```
<q-select label="Fruits" :options="['apple', 'mango']" />
```

This is what I would like Prettier to format it into automatically on save

```
<q-select 
label="Fruits" 
:options="['apple', 'mango']"
/>
```

I have tried so far using the `singleAttributePerLine` option in my `settings.json` file in VSCode according to these [release notes](https://prettier.io/blog/2022/03/16/2.6.0.html). However it does not work and VSCode does not recognize this configuration. I also could not find this setting in the settings menu for the Prettier extension. I also tried putting this option in the `.editorconfig` file but no results

My settings.json file configuration

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": ["source.fixAll.eslint"],
"eslint.validate": ["javascript", "javascriptreact", "typescript", "vue"],
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"prettier.singleAttributePerLine":true,
```

Comment: I'm using Volar for formatting, and this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669475/812919

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danny Connell (Vue educator on YT, Udemy) had the same problem and wrote a VS Code extension called "Split HTML Attributes" that formats a starting tag with multiple attributes into one attribute per line. Select the entire starting tag (with attributes inside) and then press ctrl+shift+alt+A and your tag will now be nicely formatted with one line per attribute.

You can find it at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dannyconnell.split-html-attributes&ssr=false#overview. I use it, it's very handy!

Comment: I really dislike that this requires another dependency, Vue 3 was supposed to make all of this crap easier.

Comment: Technically it's not a dependency, it's a VS Code extension. And also it's not a Vue 3 problem--many other frameworks pack lots of attributes (props) into html tags. VS Code should have a shortcut for this built-in. Also, some devs get annoyed by Prettier's opinionated formatting, and use ESLint instead for code formatting (specifically the way Prettier handles long lines/line wrapping--configuring this behavior is difficult/not possible). See https://antfu.me/posts/why-not-prettier.

Comment: Ah fair enough, will check out the article. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: You're welcome. Definitely lots of pain points being a web developer, but at least things generally seem to be moving forward and improving :).

Comment: but when the document is formatted with Volar, these changes are undone, so what's the point? 

Comment: I'm using Volar for formatting, and this worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669475/812919

Answer (score 9):

For people who use 'volar' but don't want to use 'prettier' or another extension, can achieve this by adding this to the 'settings.json':

```json
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline"
```

Alternatively you may use these options:

- force: Wrap each attribute except first.
- force-aligned: Wrap each attribute except first and keep aligned.

As explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52669475/812919

Comment: Thanks @olfek for mentioning this in the comments!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100289/how-to-enforce-new-line-per-attribute-in-vue-using-prettier-in-vs-code/75755258#comment132964841_73107257

Comment: Any idea how I can get this to apply to Vue elements?  It's exactly what I need

Comment: do you mean components? It should work for component attributes.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue, but eventually I found that when I installed Volar (I guess) it must have added this to my settings.json. It seems to over-ride the other editor.defaultFormatter.

```
"[vue]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
   }
```

I changed it to:

```
 "[vue]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
 },
```

Prettier now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use Prettier, you can add this line:

`"prettier.singleAttributePerLine": true,`

Read here:
https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#single-attribute-per-line

Answer (score 0):

Changing default formatter to Vetur worked for me:

```
"[vue]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
},
```